# Simple way to pass attributes as parameters without defining a class

Tags: python, class, function, attributes, initialization

Say I have a function:

```
def test(ab):
    print ab.a
    print ab.b
```

How can I easily pass arguments to this function without defining a class? I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
test({4,5})
```

or

```
test(ab.a = 5, ab.b = 6)
```

Is this at all possible? Changing the function 'test' is not an option.

Comment: I don't get the "without defining a class" restriction.  Is this a homework puzzle or a real problem?  Is using a namedtuple cheating?

Comment: I know various ways I could solve this by defining a class or using external libraries. The "without defining a class" restriction was just to clarify that I was looking for a way to do this quickly on one line. So I guess I am asking if there is a build-in way to do this.

Comment: The simplest way to do this that I can think of uses `namedtuple`, which returns a new subclass of tuple and therefore defines a class, and so is ruled out by your restriction.  It's usually simpler just to explain what you'd like to do and why.

Comment: I have a command line tool 'A.py'. A.py uses argparse to convert commandline arguments to argv and sends argv to some functions. I want to use these functions directly from another file by importing A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections#collections.namedtuple):

```
import collections

ab = collections.namedtuple("AB", "a b")(a=4, b=5)
test(ab)
```